# RestFul java with mongodb How to add @QueryParam

Tags: java, json, mongodb, rest

I have problem with my Restful web service on java and mongodb.

Here is my Class

```
public JSONArray returnAll () throws Exception{
    MongoClient mongoClient = mongoConnection();
    DBCollection collection = mongoClient.getDB("mydb").getCollection("zip");
    BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
    query.put("city","CHICOPEE");
    DBCursor cursor = collection.find(query);
    JSON json = new JSON();
    String serialize = json.serialize(cursor);
    JSONArray AllJson = new JSONArray(serialize);
    return AllJson;
}
```

And This is my Webservice Class

```
@Path("/All")
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response returnDatabaseAll() throws Exception{
    String returnString = null;
    JSONArray json = new JSONArray();
    try{
        greatontimeSchema dao = new greatontimeSchema();
        json = dao.returnAll();
        returnString = json.toString();
    }catch (SQLException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return Response.status(500).entity("Server was not able").build();

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return Response.status(500).entity("Server was not able").build();
    }
    return Response.ok(json).build();
}
```

This is Work for me. it's return correct JSON data like this . when i call

```
http://192.168.1.5:8080/com.projecttest.JSMongo/api/mongoWS/All
```

**[{"_id":"01013","city":"CHICOPEE","loc":[-72.607962,42.162046],"pop":23396,"state":"MA"},{"_id":"01020","city":"CHICOPEE","loc":[-72.576142,42.176443],"pop":31495,"state":"MA"}]**

But if I want to add @QueryParam to my Class like this

```
public JSONArray returnAll (String city) throws Exception{
    MongoClient mongoClient = mongoConnection();
    DBCollection collection = mongoClient.getDB("mydb").getCollection("zip");
    BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
    query.put("city",city);
    DBCursor cursor = collection.find(query);
    JSON json = new JSON();
    String serialize = json.serialize(cursor);
    JSONArray AllJson = new JSONArray(serialize);
    return AllJson;
}
```

And Change my web service class to this

```
@Path("{city}")
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response returnDatabaseAll(@QueryParam("city") String city) throws Exception{
    String returnString = null;
    JSONArray json = new JSONArray();
    try{
        greatontimeSchema dao = new greatontimeSchema();
        json = dao.returnAll(city);
        returnString = json.toString();
    }catch (SQLException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return Response.status(500).entity("Server was not able").build();

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return Response.status(500).entity("Server was not able").build();
    }
    return Response.ok(json).build();
}
```

when I enter url like this

```
http://192.168.1.5:8080/com.projecttest.JSMongo/api/mongoWS/CHICOPEE
```

it's return

[]

I'm newbie in java. I have tried to Google it but I can't find my solution.
In this case I develop it with MYSQL Database It's no problem.
But with MongoDB I really don't know.
Could anyone please help me? Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: Use `@PathParam` where you have `@QueryParam`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response returnDatabaseAll(@QueryParam("city") String city) throws Exception{
String returnString = null;
JSONArray json = new JSONArray();
try{
    greatontimeSchema dao = new greatontimeSchema();
    json = dao.returnAll(city);
    returnString = json.toString();
}catch (SQLException ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
    return Response.status(500).entity("Server was not able").build();
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    return Response.status(500).entity("Server was not able").build();
}
return Response.ok(json).build();
}
```

You can still use Queryparam with the above and your url should be,

```
http://192.168.1.5:8080/com.projecttest.JSMongo/api/mongoWS?city=CHICOPEE
```